# Visual Studio user-scoped DataGridViewCellStyle setting not saving

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, datagridviewcellstyle

I'm uncertain if this is a bug, a 'feature', or if I'm doing something incorrectly, but I'm trying to save a `DataGridViewCellStyle` as a user-scoped setting in a Windows Forms application coded in VB.NET.  I'm able to get other settings to save and load correctly, but not any DataGridViewCellStyles.

I went so far as to set up a new application to test this, and I'm having the same issue:

```
Public Class Form1



  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        My.Settings.UserDGVCellStyle = New DataGridViewCellStyle
        My.Settings.UserDGVCellStyle.Font = New Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 14, FontStyle.Italic)
        My.Settings.UserDGVCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Azure
        My.Settings.UserFont = New Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 13, FontStyle.Italic)
        My.Settings.UserBackgroundColor = Color.Black
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        My.Settings.Save()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I put a code-break on the first and last lines.  The `My.Settings.UserbackgroundColor` and `My.Settings.UserFont` settings persist when the application is closed and reopened, but `My.Settings.UserDGVCellStyle` always shows as being 'nothing' when the application is restarted (even though it shows as being

> "{DataGridViewCellStyle { BackColor=Color [Azure], Font=[Font: Name=Times New Roman, Size=14, Units=3, GdiCharSet=1, GdiVerticalFont=False] }}"

during the My.Settings.Save() line).

I realize that instead of trying to save the DataGridViewCellStyle, I could replace it with a bunch of individual settings (i.e., Font, BackColor, Alignment, etc), but I would rather not if I don't have to, as I'll have to do it many times for my application.

On a (potentially) related note, I remember having this issue when saving a DataTable, but once I filled DataTable.TableName, the table persisted successfully.

Comment: I don't think DataGridViewCellStyle is marked as serializable, so it doesn't know the instructions needed to create a new object.

Comment: Thanks @LarsTech.  It's true that "Implements ISerializable" is not part of its MSDN definition and I also read that user-scoped settings must be serializable for them to work.  Though, it would be nice if the project properties -> settings pane warned you when adding a "non-serializable" class/object to the settings so that future users don't waste as much time figuring this out as I did.

Comment: And so, you could add "DataGridViewCellStyles are not serializable and as such, are not retrievable application settings", and I'll accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: No controls are serializable.  You can write a small class representing a "StyleSet" though, save user options to a collection of them and serialize it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DataGridViewCellStyle`s are not serializable, thus they are not retrievable application settings.

There it is, now in Answer form. I came looking for the answer to this same problem, and you are right, it was a time-waster to me as well.